# The encoder utf-8 or iso-8859-1 does not show portuguese characters

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a problem. I have a web page that do not work with the characters of the portuguese language. I put on page the encoder `UTF-`8 or `ISO-8859-1(Latin 1)`, but I stil have a problem. But some pages work well other not. Below my code:

```
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title><%=Application("app")%></title>
<link href="/gen/css/css002.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
```

And here the code of caller page(only head)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/gen/css/css002.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/gen/css/tab2.css" id="luna-tab-style-sheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/gen/css/calendar-green.css" title="green" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../gen/modal/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1" src="../../gen/modal/modal.crossbrowser.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

But if I remove the include below, work very well

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../gen/modal/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1" src="../../gen/modal/modal.crossbrowser.min.js"></script>
```

When I say work well, because work with all characters of the portuguese language

Below the code of javascript(modal.crossbrowser.min.js)

```
var tituloMultiBrowser;

(function () {
    window.showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog || function (url, arg, opt) {
        url = url || '';                                     //URL
        arg = arg || null;                                   //Argumentos
        opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //Opções: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight/CSS styles

        //Função Chamadora
        var caller = showModalDialog.caller.toString();

        var doc;

        var i = 0;

        if (window.parent.name == 'JANELASISAMIL') {
            doc = window.parent.document;
        }
        else {
            var janela = window.parent.name;
            var janelaPai = window.parent;
            while (janela != 'JANELASISAMIL' && i <= 20) {
                janelaPai = janelaPai.parent;
                janela = janelaPai.parent.name;
                i++;
            }
            doc = janelaPai.parent.document;
        }

        i = sessionStorage.getItem('id_toolbar_modal');

        sessionStorage.setItem('id_toolbar_browser', 'multi');

        //Preparar style conforme argumentos/opções de posicionamento
        var styleClean = opt.replace(/dialog/gi, '');// + '; cursor:move;';

        //Montar <div> para container
        var elDiv = doc.createElement('div');
        elDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wndModal_' + i);

        //Montar <span> para título
        var elSpan = doc.createElement('span');
        elSpan.style['background'] = '#5c9ccc';
        elSpan.style['color'] = '#fff';
        elSpan.style['text-overflow'] = 'ellipsis';
        elSpan.style['float'] = 'left';
        elSpan.style['width'] = '96%';
        elSpan.style['font-weight'] = 'bold';
        elSpan.style['padding'] = '5px';
        elSpan.style['cursor'] = 'move';
        elSpan.style['border-top-left-radius'] = '5px';
        elSpan.style['border-top-right-radius'] = '5px';
        elSpan.style['border-bottom-left-radius'] = '5px';
        elSpan.style['border-bottom-right-radius'] = '5px';
        elSpan.innerHTML = tituloMultiBrowser;
        elDiv.appendChild(elSpan);

        //Montar <a> para close
        var elClose = doc.createElement('a');
        elClose.setAttribute('href', '#');
        elClose.setAttribute('id', 'dialog-close_' + i);
        elClose.style['position'] = 'absolute';
        elClose.style['top'] = '0';
        elClose.style['right'] = '4px';
        elClose.style['font-size'] = '20px';
        elClose.style['color'] = '#555';
        elClose.style['text-decoration'] = 'none';
        elClose.style['outline'] = 'none';
        elClose.style['margin-right'] = '7px';
        elClose.style['margin-top'] = '7px';
        elClose.innerHTML = '&times;';
        elDiv.appendChild(elClose);

        //Montar <iframe> para URL
        var elFrame = doc.createElement('iframe');
        elFrame.setAttribute('id', 'dialog-body_' + i);
        elFrame.setAttribute('src', url);
        elFrame.setAttribute('style', 'border: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%;');
        elDiv.appendChild(elFrame);

        //Montar <dialog> para executar showModal (Compatibilidade Chrome 37+)
        var elDialog = doc.createElement('dialog');

        //Coletar o Node de <dialog>
        var dialog = doc.body.appendChild(elDialog);
        dialog.setAttribute('style', styleClean);
        dialog.style['border'] = 'solid';
        dialog.style['border-color'] = '#333';
        dialog.style['border-width'] = '1px';
        dialog.style['border-top-left-radius'] = '5px';
        dialog.style['border-top-right-radius'] = '5px';
        dialog.style['border-bottom-left-radius'] = '5px';
        dialog.style['border-bottom-right-radius'] = '5px';
        dialog.innerHTML = elDiv.outerHTML;

        //Setar o 'que seria' o dialogArguments do showModalDialog
        doc.getElementById('dialog-body_' + i).contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;

        //Setar o atributo (novo) dialogWindow para fechá-lo posteriormente
        doc.getElementById('dialog-body_' + i).contentWindow.dialogWindow = dialog;

        //Evento click do link de fechamento
        doc.getElementById('dialog-close_' + i).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.close();
        });

        dialog.showModal();

        //Procurar na função 'chamadora' a chamada para showModalDialog
        var encontrouShowModalDialog = false;
        var proximaInstrucao = caller.split('\n').filter(function (instrucao) {
            if (encontrouShowModalDialog || instrucao.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0) {
                return encontrouShowModalDialog = true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        //Incorpora comportamento drag (através de jQuery UI)
        try {
            $(doc.getElementById('wndModal_' + i)).parent().draggable();
        }
        catch (e) {
        }

        //Evento close do elemento <dialog>
        dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
            //Coleta retorno da 'janela' Modal
            var retorno = doc.getElementById('dialog-body_' + i).contentWindow.returnValue;

            //Remove <dialog>
            doc.body.removeChild(dialog);

            //Trocar o 'var ret = window.showModalDialog(...);' por 'var ret = abcde;'
            proximaInstrucao[0] = proximaInstrucao[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(retorno));

            //'Termina' o 'resto' de código da função chamadora
            eval('{\n' + proximaInstrucao.join('\n'));
        });

        //Parar execução do script (aguardando o close do dialog)
        throw 'Aguardar retorno de showModalDialog';
    };
})();

function AbrePesquisaCrossBrowser(urlPesq, img_name, Titulo, vWidth, vHeight, vTop, vLeft, vModal) {
    var documentMulti = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
    if (isNaN(vWidth))
        vWidth = 400;

    if (isNaN(vHeight))
        vHeight = 300;

    if (isNaN(vTop))
        vTop = 100;

    if (isNaN(vLeft))
        vLeft = 100;

    if ((isNaN(vModal) && vModal != 'S') || (BrowserDetect.browser != 'Explorer'))
        vModal = 'N';

    vModal = 'S';

    urlPesq = urlPesq.replace("?", "$$$");

    var vURL = '/ace/ace005a.asp?' + urlPesq + '&Titulo=' + Titulo;

    if (((vModal == 'S') && (documentMulti && window.print)) && (BrowserDetect.browser != 'Opera')) {

        tituloMultiBrowser = Titulo;
        var vRetorno = window.showModalDialog(vURL, document.getElementsByName('form01')[0], "center:yes;help:0;status:no;resizable:no;scrollbars:yes;dialogTop:" + vTop + "px;dialogWidth:" + vWidth + "px;dialogHeight:" + vHeight + 'px;unadorned:yes;');

        if (vRetorno == undefined) {
            vRetorno = window.returnValue;
            if (vRetorno != "")
                eval(vRetorno);
        }
    }
    else {
        eval('window.open(vURL,"","width=' + vWidth + ',height=' + vHeight + ',top=' + vTop + ',left=' + vLeft + ',resizable=1,scrollbars=no")');
    }
}
```

I can not to put the image here(work well and not), I don't know why.

See that there is nothing different in the code above

This is a old site was writing in classic asp and the purpose is to work in `google-chrome`

What should I do? These are my attempts.

I changed by the UTF-8 encoder and nothing, still the same thing.

Comment: `content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" ` tells the browser to interpret the text as `iso-8859-1`, but that doesn't mean that the text actually **is** `iso-8859-1`.

Comment: @Popnoodles, I tryed to put the images, but locks the site. I tryed twice.

Comment: Add the links to the images as a comment

Comment: @zeroflagL, how can I do to my page shows portuguese characters?